# Django: Make a GET Request to a URL that is advanced

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I have Chat Rooms and I have Messages. Then I have two urls: /messages and /rooms. And these display all your rooms and messages. Also a message can be assigned to a room. So in the Room API I have the messages assigned to that room.

Let's say that the room is called 'Room1' and the messages are 'hey', 'yo' and 'wassup'. If I make a request to just /messages I will get all of the messages. Let's say that only two of the messages are assigned to 'Room1' and the other message is assigned to another room not named.

I want a way to make a get request and only get those two messages assigned to 'Room1 with id = 3' (localhost:8000/rooms/3/messages) instead of: (localhost:8000/messages).

This is an example of when I make a get request to /rooms/3/

```
   {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Room 1",
    "members": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "william"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "eric"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "ryan"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "content": "hej",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "william"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "content": "yoyo",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "eric"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "content": "tjo bror",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 3,
            "username": "ryan"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "content": "hej jag heter Eric och jag gar pa polhemskolan i lund och jag ar 17 ar gammal",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "eric"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "content": "vi vet hahah",
        "date": "2019-07-09",
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "william"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "content": "amen sluta",
        "date": "2019-07-09",
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "eric"
        }
    }
 ]
 }
```

This is what I want to get in response if I do rooms/3/messages:

```
       "messages": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "content": "hej",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "william"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "content": "yoyo",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "eric"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "content": "tjo bror",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 3,
            "username": "ryan"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "content": "hej jag heter Eric och jag gar pa polhemskolan i lund och jag ar 17 ar gammal",
        "date": "2019-07-08",
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "eric"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "content": "vi vet hahah",
        "date": "2019-07-09",
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "william"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "content": "amen sluta",
        "date": "2019-07-09",
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "eric"
        }
    }
  ]
  }
```

Django Models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
     verbose_name_plural = 'All Users'

def __str__(self):
     return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_data(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
if created:
    user = instance
    profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="sendermessage")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    canview = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="messagecanview")

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Messages'

def __str__(self):
    return "{sender}".format(sender=self.sender)

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Rooms'

def __str__(self):
    return "{name}".format(name=self.name)enter code here
```

Django Serializers:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'username')

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = UserProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'date', 'sender')

class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    messages = MessageSerializer(many=True)
    members = UserProfileSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'members', 'messages')
```

Django Views:

```
class UserProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

class UserMessageView(MessageView):
def get_queryset(self):
    return Message.objects.filter(canview__user=self.request.user)

class RoomView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer

class UserRoomView(RoomView):
def get_queryset(self):
    return Room.objects.filter(members__user=self.request.user)
```

Django Urls:

```
 router = routers.DefaultRouter()
 router.register('users', views.UserProfileView),
 router.register('rooms', views.UserRoomView),
 router.register('messages', views.UserMessageView),

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: Can you write out an example? :)

Comment: In my not so humble opinion, `localhost:8000/messages` is the home for the `Message` resources, so you should filter on that instead of creating a path beneath room. I'll show that.

Answer (score 1):

To get all `Messages` assigned to a room, let's:

#### Install django-filter:

```
pip install django-filter
```

#### Modify the `Room` model to specify a `related_name`:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True, related_name='rooms')
    #                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Enable filtering for the `rooms` related field:

```
import django_filters
import rest_framework.filters

[...]

class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # vvvvvvvvvvv  I don't think this line is needed vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    # http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerialize

    filter_backends = (
        django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend, 
        rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter,
    )
    filter_fields = ['rooms']
```

Then, you can request all messages for that room with a `GET` to:

```
localhost:8000/messages/?rooms=3
```

## Comment question:

You also need to expose the `Message` object's `sender` field. Currently it is aliased:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #     vvvv                         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    sender_obj = UserProfileSerializer(source='sender', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'date', 'sender', 'sender_obj')
        #                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then you can `POST` to `/message` with the data `{"content": "blah", "date": "2019-07-09","sender": 1}`

Comment: Oops.  `filters` isn't exported by default from the library.  Change import to `import rest_framework.filters`

Comment: thanks mate but when I then make a post request to the url I get NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_message.sender_id

Comment: `POST` is another whole deal.  Looks like you need a valid `sender` field on the `POST`.

Comment: For some reason this dosen't work: "sender": {"username": "william"}, note that it is a ManyToManyField relationship

Comment: You need to change `MessageSerializer` to expose the actual `sender` field, which is a primary key and accepts integers.  If you want to send the `User` object down with the message, I'd use a different name like `sender_obj` so you can `POST` a `Message` with data like `{"content": "blah", "date": "2019-07-09","sender": 1}`

Comment: Can you put that in the code above? Would help loads :)

Comment: Done.  See above.

Comment: Do you want me to do "sender_obj": 1 or "sender": 1?

Comment: `sender_obj` is a READ-ONLY copy of the entire `sender` `User` object in the database.  `sender` is the primary key `id` field of the `User`.  You must send an integer on field `sender`.

Comment: Also, if I've helped you, upvote and then accept my answer.  I'll keep working with you.

Comment: I'll do that :) But I still get the KeyError at /chat/messages.   'sender'

Comment: This is the error I got : TypeError at /chat/messages/
create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not UserProfile

Comment: What is the data you sent down?

Comment: {
 "content": "aaasss",
 "sender": 1
}

Comment: def create(self, validated_data):
        sender_data = validated_data.pop('sender')
        sender = UserProfile.objects.create(**sender_data)
        return Message.objects.create(sender=sender, **validated_data)

Comment: btw i have this, forgot to say

Comment: When I try to make a post request to the messages in a specific room it won't work tho? Like to messages/?room=4/

Comment: Why are you overriding `create` ?   Your `UserProfile` should be created before the `Message` is sent.  As it is, I think you're trying to create a new `UserProfile` on each `POST` to `/message`.  You should just send the `UserProfile` `id` with the message.  As to how to add a message to a room, you need to expose the `rooms` `related_field` on your `MessageSerializer` by adding `rooms` to the end of your `fields` tuple.  Then you should be able to post a list on the `rooms` field like `{ "content": "foodefafa", "sender": 1, "rooms":42 }`

Comment: yea it works now but I have another problem, the last comment I wrote! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994574/post-request-to-django-rest-api-that-has-a-filter-so-messages-room-4